# Check which php functions will work in a specific php version

Tags: php

At least this shows I'm not afraid to look stupid.  Here it goes:
At some point while writing my php project, I determined that it would need php verion 5.2 to work properly.  I didn't document why.  Now, a user is asking me what will break if they run my app on 5.1 and I simply can't remember.

Is there any automated way to check which functions will fail using 5.1.  I looked at PHP_CodeSniffer, but I'm not sure that will do what I want.  Any thoughts?

Comment: tell them "I don't support users using 5.1 so unfortunately, I'm not allowed to further assist you. However, if you do find out, tell me."

Comment: Have you read [this section in the documentation](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/migration52.php)? Aso, keep in mind that neither 5.1 nor 5.2 are officially supported these days.

Comment: A good place to start would be the [migration notes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration52.php), specifically the breaks to BC and new functionality. The [changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.0) will give more technical information. However, 5.2 and below are no longer supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test certain functions with [3v4l.org](http://3v4l.org/). This supports multiple php-versions where you can test your functions in.

Comment: That's really useful, thanks.  Now, if only it could spider my entire project and give a report, that would be perfect.